# How do I calculate the difference between a day and the corresponding day a week before in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I hava `pandas` `DataFrame` like this, where `date` is the index:

```
| date       |   cases |
|:-----------|--------:|
| 2020-03-30 |       5 |
| 2020-04-01 |       9 |
| 2020-04-03 |      10 |
| 2020-04-06 |      13 |
| 2020-04-08 |      16 |
```

I would like to calculate the difference between some date, and the date a week before. So in the case above it would be 8 for the `2020-04-06` (13 for the 2020-04-06 - 2020-03-30), 7 for 2020-04-08 (- 2020-04-01), and so on.

I've tried with `df.diff` and `df.shift(freq=7)` but sometimes the offset days are not a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `shift`

```
s = df.set_index('date').cases
df['diff' ] = df.date.map(s - s.shift(freq='7 D'))
df
Out[219]: 
        date  cases  diff
0 2020-03-30      5   NaN
1 2020-04-01      9   NaN
2 2020-04-03     10   NaN
3 2020-04-06     13   8.0
4 2020-04-08     16   7.0
```

Comment: thanks! the problem is that my "date" is already the index...

Answer (score 2):

Try subtracting a week from the date and then map the cases based on `date` , then subtract:

```
df['cases']-(df['date'] - pd.Timedelta(weeks=1)).map(df.set_index('date')['cases'])
```

---

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    8.0
4    7.0
dtype: float64
```

---

```
df['Difference'] = (df['cases']-(df['date'] - pd.Timedelta(weeks=1))
                .map(df.set_index('date')['cases']))
print(df)

        date  cases  Difference
0 2020-03-30      5         NaN
1 2020-04-01      9         NaN
2 2020-04-03     10         NaN
3 2020-04-06     13         8.0
4 2020-04-08     16         7.0
```

Comment: thanks, it tells me: `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`